PHP memory issues with exceptions supporting __set
There is a custom exception class (which I have reduced to its minimum for this posting):
<?php
  class MyException extends \Exception {
    public final function __set(String $member, $value) {
  }
}
?>

__set() is not used anywhere; in the original version it simply throws an \Exception and was introduced to prevent accidental writes to $e->nonexistingproperty which is deprecated already and hopefully soon will be forbidden anyway.
And there is a code fragment (which is embedded in a much larger piece of software):
try {
    var_dump(memory_get_usage());
    echo "<br>";
    $e = new MyException();
    var_dump(memory_get_usage());
    echo "<br>";
    throw $e;
}               
catch (\Throwable) {
    var_dump(memory_get_usage());
    echo "<br>";
    var_dump(get_class($e));
    echo "<br>";
    unset($e);
    var_dump(memory_get_usage());
}     

Running it I get the following output (the fragment starts with line 407 in the actual file):
contextlevel.php:408: int(3207080)
contextlevel.php:411: int(3216336)
contextlevel.php:416: int(3473200)
contextlevel.php:418: string(11) "MyException"
contextlevel.php:421: int(3463904)

Throwing (not creating!) the exception costs a lot of memory.
If I remove the (irrelevant) __set throwing the exception still costs a lot of memory, but now it gets freed with unset($e). Why? (Look at the overall change of the memory footprint - just by removing an unused safety-guard method!)
contextlevel.php:408: int(2042552)
contextlevel.php:411: int(2051776)
contextlevel.php:416: int(2309016)
contextlevel.php:418: string(11) "MyException"
contextlevel.php:421: int(2057712)

I failed to reproduce this effect with a minimum working example, because the (jittering) numbers are too low then. Still this is 100% reproducible in my real-world software.
I can and will of course drop the __set() and thus the problem I failed to properly describe yesterday should be solved. But still I would be interested why this happens. Any insights?
Update: after playing around a lot the culprit seems to be xdebug, even if run with only develop mode active; if the module is disabled, the memory overhead is gone immediately, otherwise it seems to be a constant (at least for a given class) which is added for each call.

I got only 32 bytes increase with or without the magic method. Maybe this is a problem with your environment (php version, extensions, etc.).

@shingo That's what I meant: If I try it isolated (with the same PHP version/extensions), I can't illustrate the problem either. Still it exists and I can't see any possible influences by the rest of the software. Likely only persons with deep PHP insights might be able answer that.

Memory must NOT be freed when you unset it. It is marked for garbage collection and will be deleted when its schedule runs or is forced.

@MarkusZeller "Memory must NOT be freed when you unset it" It is freed if the reference count reaches zero (as explained here).

@Olivier Read next chapter, too: Only when the root buffer is full does the collection mechanism start for all the different zvals inside.

@MarkusZeller In PHP, garbage collection only deals with cycles. If an object is part of a cycle, then its reference counter never reaches zero, and it stays in memory until GC activates.
